# How to get SQL data on a new page, based on something selected on a previous page using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

I am new to this and am trying to come up with a basic system which will automatically get product names from an SQL database, and then once one is clicked, a product page will appear with the relevant product details. My plan was to have a single product page which would later be filled with data from and SQL database, based on which product was selected. The issue I have is getting the product page to recognise which product has been selected, so it can get the relevant details from the database. Any ideas? I am new to this and trying to learn PHP at the same time.

If I have not explained this very well I apologise, feel free to ask me questions. Thank you.

Comment: you should be selecting from the database based on a key, like an id for example. "SELECT * FROM products where id=1" would return the results to a product with an id of 1.

Comment: Well on the page with all items I have used SQL and PHP to display all product_name in tbl_products. Its when one of those is selected, I want a new page to get sql data related to just the one product. I can do this manually, with a new page for every product but I wanted one single page to work for all products, updating the info based on what had been selected on the previous page.

Comment: I have echo'd some HTML which links all products found to the same single product page.

Comment: Your links from the products page, which displays all products, should be reflective of the ID field for example. You can link to something like product.php?id=1 - then take the $_GET['id'] field in a query to only fetch the one product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a page where you pass in the product ID as a GET parameter and link to it from your product list page.

So the product list page would have a link for each product name:

```
<a href="product.php?id=1">Product Name</a>
...
<a href="product.php?id=2">Another Product</a>
```

Then in your `product.php` page you would get the product id from the request, like so:

```
$product_id = $_GET['id'];
```

And use that in your query to pull in the product details for that particular product.